Floor jack and jack stand placement — Jacking up rear wheel of truck
2010 Silverado 1500 extended cab 5000 lbs 4wd:
I'm a novice learning about jacking up trucks. The goal is to lift the rear-left wheel off of the ground so that I can do bodywork in the wheel well area.
Are there any safety risks with the way I jacked up the truck?

Steps:

Engage parking brake. I'm aware that doesn't do anything when both rear wheels are temporarily off the ground.
Placed wheel chocks at both front wheels. One of the front wheels has chocks on both sides of the wheel.
Jack up the rear of the truck (both wheels) by using a  3.5-ton floor jack on the rear differential. Both wheels are off the ground. I was careful to position the jack away from the rear differential cover to avoid damaging it. The floor jack saddle fits well into the spaces between the fins on the rear differential.
Place a 6-ton jack stand under the bracket on the left side of the axle. I don't know what the bracket is called.
Slowly lower the floor jack so that the axle/bracket rests on the axle stand.
The rear-left wheel is still elevated off of the ground, allowing me to remove the wheel and do the work.







Chock both sides of each front wheel. If you use one stand on the rear left, chock both sides of the rear right wheel after the left axle has dropped onto the stand and the right wheel has dropped to the ground, and before you get underneath (not before so that there's no contention as you jack it up).
